# Does a simpler representation of this if condition exist?

Tags: java, c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

I used the below conditional statement to ensure that the city name given is of valid length. Length of city should be greater than or equal to 3 **and** less than or equal to 20.

```
if(city.length()<3 || city.length()>20) return false;
else return true;
```

I am told that this conditional statement can be further simplified. Is that right? Then what is the simplified code?

Comment: return !(city.length()<3 || city.length()>20)

Comment: Drop the whole `if/else` business and just return the thing, also drop some language tags

Comment: [Please do not tag multiple languages in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question/) unless your question is specifically about these languages.  You may think it will lead to a faster answer, but the reality is that it is more likely to lead to a faster closure.

Comment: If the diff. of the two interval endpoints were even, there would be.

Comment: The question is actually incomplete.   What type does `city.length()` return?   And, on two consecutive calls like this, is it guaranteed to return the same value?

Answer (score 2):

```
return !(city.length() < 3 || city.length() > 20)
```

or

```
return city.length() >= 3 && city.length() <= 20
```

Answer (score 2):

I simplified your code from IntelliJ IDEA IDE.

Actually it itself suggested to simplify when I used your code there. I recommend you to try IntelliJ IDEA.

```
return city.length() >= 3 && city.length() <= 20;
```

If you are already using the IDE, just move the cursor to the code with warning and press ALT+Enter and simplify it.

Comment: and I would honestly recommend not to rely on an IDE for such simple tasks, it should be obvious that the statements can be simplified and are equivalent.

Comment: @luk2302 we can have different opinions. Refactors using IDE can be helpful to beginners.

Comment: on eclipse, does any plugin exists to suggest this

Comment: sorry, i haven't used eclipse. please search for that in google.

Answer (score 2):

If `city.length()` is cheap, then write

```
return city.length() >= 3 && city.length() <= 20
```

else you ought to pre-compute `city.length()` to avoid the potential for two evaluations:

```
const auto&& /*assuming C++, for Java, you need to use the specific type*/ l = city.length();
return l >= 3 && l <= 20;
```

Comment: Suggestion: use auto&& for l. This way, if city.length() returns a reference to a complex type (e.g. has a std::string measure;), you won't copy it but have a ref.